# Passing URL variables in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, url

I'm sure if I'm going about this the right way, but I need to pass the form variables in the URL redirect. The redirect is working, but I can't get the data to output.

```
$("#promoForm").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
        lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        code: $("#code").val()
    };

    if ( isValidEmail(data['email']) && (data['firstname'].length > 1) && (data['lastname'].length > 1) && (data['code'].length > 1) ) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/promo.php",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $('.success.pf').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
                $('.failed.pf').fadeOut(500);
                setTimeout(function() {
                  window.location.href = "http://demo.example.com/signup?firstname=+data['firstname']+lastname=+data['lastname']+email=+data['email']+code=+data['code']"
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.failed.pf').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
        $('.success.pf').fadeOut(500);
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can save yourself some typing by just doing `data.email` instead of `data['email']`...

Comment: Your `+` is still inside the quotes.  JavaScript doesn't know you want to concatenate strings, it just sees a literal plus sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using variables to construct the URL:

```
window.location.href = "http://demo.example.com/signup?firstname=+data['firstname']+lastname=+data['lastname']+email=+data['email']+code=+data['code']"
```

Instead, close the string with `"` and append the values and follow-up strings:

```
window.location.href = "http://demo.example.com/signup?firstname=" + data['firstname'] + "lastname=" + data['lastname'] + "email=" + data['email'] + "code=" + data['code']
```

Additionally, you seem to be missing the parameter separators (`&`), so I should probably be:

```
window.location.href = "http://demo.example.com/signup?firstname=" + data['firstname'] + "&lastname=" + data['lastname'] + "&email=" + data['email'] + "&code=" + data['code']
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and giving me a detailed answer. I still have a lot to learn but I am very grateful for this community and users like yourself. #Gratitude

Comment: Are you coming from PHP? Because `"string and $variable"` works there, but not in (most) other languages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
window.location.href = "http://demo.example.com/signup?firstname="+data['firstname']+"lastname="+data['lastname']+"email"=+data['email']+"code="+data['code']
```

Comment: This shouldn’t be about “trying”. It should be about understanding the problem, the misconception, and enriching knowledge. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). “Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.” I’m pretty sure you can do better 